# -bash: cmd: command not found

Tags: bash, unicorn, init.d

I have this in /etc/init.d/unicorn

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/unicorn

# ### BEGIN INIT INFO
# chkconfig: 2345 95 016
# processname: unicorn
# dscription: Stop/start unicorn
### END INIT INFO

export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

cmd() {
    cd /vagrant
    unicorn -p 3000 -D
}

# Start the service
start() {
    su - vagrant -c cmd
}

### main logic ###
case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start}"
        exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

I am trying to start unicorn in my local rails folder. I feel like this command should work:

```
su - vagrant -c cmd
```

and  cannot figure out the reason.

Comment: why are you exporting `PATH` without a reference to `$PATH`?  Why are you using `su` to run a command?  Use `sudo`.  Or use `sudo -s` at start of script so that you become root.  Or better yet, just always run the script as root.

Comment: @AlexejMagura This is an init script. It always runs as root. He uses su because he wants a command to run as a non-root user.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are under the impression that the shell function `cmd` which is defined in that script should be available in the shell which has started that script earlier.

This is wrong, unless you `source`d that script (which is unusual for scripts in `/etc/init.d/`).  When you start a script (not `source` it), then you start a second process which executes the script.  All definitions of shell functions (like that `cmd`) are valid only within that shell script and die with the process.

In case you really want the `cmd` to be available, you will have to `source` the script `unicorn`:

```
source /etc/init.d/unicorn
```

The `su` command, however, will still not be able to call that shell function because it only can call executables it can start using `exec()`, so they need to be a file.  A shell function isn't.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, inline the function in the shell invoked by `su`:

```
start() {
    su - vagrant -c 'cd /vagrant && unicorn -p 3000 -D'
}
```

and as for figuring out the reason in the first place, tooling is helpful:

```
$ shellcheck unicorn

In unicorn line 19:
    su - vagrant -c cmd
                    ^-- SC2033: Shell functions can't be passed to external commands.
```